# How to fetch first 5 decimal location value without round()

Tags: python-3.x

precise decimal digit **without** using round()

I am using python3 and django 1.11.5

Suppose a = 92.466578699

Expected result a = 92.46657

Comment: Output where? On the console, as a string? And why not `92.46658`, shouldn't it be rounded up? And how is django relevant, you want to round it in the template?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limiting floats to two decimal points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455612/limiting-floats-to-two-decimal-points)

Comment: @ schwobaseggl: Thanks for your response . Actually I have to compare two outputs but they are different at 10 decimal digit . Suppose a = 92.466578698 and b = 92.466578699. I want to check the output upto 8 decimal limit which will solve my issue.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isclose might be useful

Comment: Is there a reason you do not want to use round?

Comment: Yes, C. Lewis. I have already mentioned above as " I have to compare two outputs but they are different at 10 decimal digit . Suppose a = 92.466578698 and b = 92.466578699. I want to check the output upto 8 decimal limit which will solve my issue"

Comment: @user2412309 answered my question. Thanks everyone for your participation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try format

```
format(1.242563,".2f")
```

The output would be:

```
1.33243
```

Another

```
 print (format(1.332432,".5f"))
 1.33243
```